# Cannot use text file as type byte with Golang in Write method

Tags: go

I tried to merge fileACopy.txt`to`tmp1.txt` by appending fileACopy.txt to tmp1.txt and then deleting fileACopy.txt.

My intended process...

1. Open fileACopy.txt with os.Open("./fileACopy.txt") then store the contents in the "fileACopy" variable.
2. Open and set the "append" variable to tmp1.txt with os.OpenFile("tmp1.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644).
3. Write the contents of the "fileACopy" variable to "append" with Write().
4. Remove the "fileACopy.txt" file with os.Remove("fileACopy.txt")

Code:

```
    fileACopy, err := os.Open("./fileACopy.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer fileACopy.Close()

    append, err := os.OpenFile("tmp1.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer append.Close()

    if _, err := append.Write(fileACopy); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err := os.Remove("fileACopy.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Error:

```
Cannot use 'fileACopy' (type *File) as type []byte"
```

Is there a method that can use "type *File" to write one text file into another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the definitions of [Open](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open) and [Write](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write):

```
func Open(name string) (*File, error)
func (f *File) Write(b []byte) (n int, err error)
```

So the line:

```
fileACopy, err := os.Open("./fileACopy.txt")
```

Gives you `fileACopy` (a `*File`) and you then pass this as an argument to `append.Write(fileACopy)`. As per the above definitions `append.Write` takes a `[]byte` and you are trying to pass it something different (`fileACopy`, a `*File`) hence the error "Cannot use 'fileACopy' (type *File) as type []byte".

The simplest way to achieve what you want is probably to use [io.Copy](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy):

```
Copy(dst Writer, src Reader) (written int64, err error)
```

In your case `io.Copy(append, fileACopy)` should do the trick. A, less efficient, alternative would be to read the file contents using [ioutil.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) (amoungst other options) which will give you a `[]byte` which you can then pass to `append.Write` (this may not work as well because the entire file is read into memory and then written).